# i2cdetect doesn't catch ANY address (no device detection)

Tags: i2c

I have ti046b1 chip (Serial I2C F-RAM) to read.

I tried to read it with my raspberry Pi 3, so I connected SDA SCL VDD GND as shown in pictures, but when I run the command "i2cdetect -y 1" on my Raspberry it shows no device connected to I2C interface (empty) like that:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

do you have any idea to solve that ?

- I tried by inverting (swiping)  SDA SLC connections
- I tried by pulling-up to 3.3V SDA and SCL with 10k resistors (as stated [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7664)) to end-up with 1.5K pull-up resistance
- I checked that there are a built in pull-up 1.8K resistors in the raspberry 3 (see the ohmmeter measure with Pi powerd off of course :) )
- I tried to change I2C baudrate by the command:

  **sudo modprobe -r i2c_bcm2708**

  **sudo modprobe i2c_bcm2708 baudrate=100000**

tested with 100KHZ, 200KHZ, 400KHZ, 800KHZ, 1200KHZ (the result is the same

- I have put a scope probes on SCL and SDA when the printer is powered on to see how it negociate (see the piture below)

could you please help me to solve that ?

And to anticipate your first question : I checked all the connections for this wiring :)

scope probes on SCL and SDA when the printer is powered with the chip is inside
[image: Scope probes on SDA SCL]
[image: Circuit Chip and schematic]
Existing pi 3 built-in pull-up 1.8K proven (pi is not powered)
[image: internal Pull-Up resistor]
[image: i2cdetect response]

[image: I2C is enabled]

[image: Wiring to my Raspberry Pi 3]

Comment: Are you sure it's a 3V3 device?  Have you a datasheet link?  You SHOULD NOT use additional pull-ups (SDA/SCL already have hard pull-ups on the Pi).

Comment: Those joints look a little sketchy.

Comment: Yes I am sure: this chip is a printer chip, so I connected a voltmeter to it when the chip is inside the printer, and the voltage is 3V3 when it is powered by the printer

Comment: Yes I admet that the joints are sketchy :) but the continuity is ensured

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the I2C interface? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: `i2cdetect` throws an error if the bus isn't already enabled.

Comment: yes it is enabeled by the command: sudo raspi-config and the command ls /dev/*i2c* answers by : /dev/i2c-1

Answer (score 0):

You missed the required pullups, there aren't any provisioned on the host GPIO (because I²C is only one of the possible functions of these two GPIOs) and your device does not have them either.

But you need them, about 3.3kΩ from SDA to +3.3V and another 3.3kΩ from SCL to +3.3V.

Comment: The Pi has 1.8kΩ pullups on board.

Comment: No ! there is already a built in pull-up 1.8k resistor in the raspberry pi 3 between SDA-3.3V and SCL-3.3V (I have measured that for you, see the picture)

Comment: Well, no clue then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [other people](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/lexmark-toner-chip-ti046b1/msg1325210/#msg1325210) over on EEVBlog forums have been trying to reverse-engineer this printer cartridge chip and have had some success. If they are correct then it uses 10-bit addressing so `i2cdetect` will not find it as it only scans the 7-bit address space. Strangely there's someone asking a [similar question](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/lexmark-toner-chip-ti046b1/msg2023609/#msg2023609) to yours on that forum too...

Also, from the same discussion, some people are suggesting that this chip is not FRAM memory but actually a re-badged processor with hardware AES *pretending* to be a FRAM chip.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by adding to the /boot/config.txt

dtparam=i2c_arm=on

dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3

and reboot the PI.